# javascript random image generator

Tags: javascript, html, generator

I want to make a container with 25 Images which are random generated out of 72 Images and i dont want the container have the same image twice. This is the code i have made. Thanks for help!

Here is the Project:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            *{padding: 0;margin: 0;}
            .lotto{width: 600px;height: 600px;}
            .bild{height: 96px;width: 96px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-right: 10px;}
            @media screen and (max-width:600px){.lotto{width: 400px;height: 400px;}.bild{height: 64px;width: 64px;padding-top: 6px;padding-left: 6px;padding-bottom: 6px;padding-right: 6px;}}
            @media screen and (max-width:400px){.lotto{width: 300px;height: 300px;}.bild{height: 48px;width: 48px;padding-top: 4px;padding-left: 4px;padding-bottom: 4px;padding-right: 4px;}}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Lotto">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    function Emoji(){
                    var myimages=new Array()
                    myimages[1]="img_1.png"
                    myimages[2]="img_2.png"
                    myimages[3]="img_3.png"
                    myimages[4]="img_4.png"
                    myimages[5]="img_5.png"
                    myimages[6]="img_6.png"
                    myimages[7]="img_7.png"
                    myimages[8]="img_8.png"
                    myimages[9]="img_9.png"
                    myimages[10]="img_10.png"
                    myimages[11]="img_11.png"
                    myimages[12]="img_12.png"
                    myimages[13]="img_13.png"
                    myimages[14]="img_14.png"
                    myimages[15]="img_15.png"
                    myimages[16]="img_16.png"
                    myimages[17]="img_17.png"
                    myimages[18]="img_18.png"
                    myimages[19]="img_19.png"
                    myimages[20]="img_20.png"
                    myimages[21]="img_21.png"
                    myimages[22]="img_22.png"

                    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
                    if (ry==0)
                    ry=1
                    document.write('<a href="#"><img class="bild" src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0></a>')
                    }
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">Emoji()</script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to search for [random without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+random+without+replacement).  A random selection based on a [Fischer-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+Fischer-Yates+shuffle) would be appropriate.

Comment: If your index of the images array matches the image number, why not just loop it?

Comment: Best way would be to store these elements in an array and store the index of the rendered images and check to make sure that the images index hasnt been used yet. Of course, when the user refreshes the page this will start over. Just a thought.

Comment: You are putting too much work into this. Try looking into the jQuery api as well. What you should do is call the emoji() function on document.ready and make that function append each image to its container...23  times.

Comment: Hey, once you have your array of 23 image urls do this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yardpenalty/qhpjtyf2/2/). Of course you will have to add html to render an img html but use element as url

Comment: What is your actual question? What is happening with your current code that shouldn't happen?  What isn't happening that should?

Comment: This is my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/gjkdrc0a/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way to do what you want, is to return a shuffle array and to insert in the DOM element in the emoji function. This is a function to shuffle an array.

```
var shuffle = function (array) {

    var currentIndex = array.length;
    var temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;

};
```

You can use it that way : `shuffle(myimages);`

**EDIT :**

What I mean is that you can put everything in two functions.

The first is the shuffle, and the second is "emoji" one.

You could do something like:

```
 function Emoji(){
    var myimages=new Array()
  for(i=0; i < 23;i++) {
    myimages[i]="img_" + i +".png";
    }
  shuffle(myimages);
  //And then add it in the DOM element
  let lotto = document.getElementsByClassName('Lotto');
  for(j=0; j < 10; j++) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = myimages[j];
    img.classList.add("bild");
    a.appendChild(img);
    lotto[0].appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

With i for the number of img in total, and j for the number that you want !

**SOURCE :**

https://gomakethings.com/how-to-shuffle-an-array-with-vanilla-js/
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: I dont understand how to use it with the code can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Thanks but which dom element? what you mean with dom Element? sorry im a noob at javascript

Comment: I like the idea of creating a dynamic array of the 23 image urls on dom ready.

Comment: About the DOM element, you can read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Comment: Marin, bro you can't edit my code you have to make your own jsfiddle and share it...

Comment: thanks man but when i try it out it worked but there is one image with the name img_0 but i dont have one with this name i only have from img_1 to img_72

Comment: Then in the "for" i=1; 1<73;i++

Comment: Bro I am so happy right now because it works... Thanks!!!!! Everything works fine. This Feeling is so nice

Comment: You're welcome, but you have to re-build and re-think the way you're asking for help! Don't forget to say that the question is answered

Answer (score 1):

I used this way in my project.
**Create a shuffle function:**

```
function shuffle(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var m = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [arr[i], arr[m]] = [arr[m], arr[i]];
    }
}
```

**After i create a array with 72 numbers like this:**

```
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27, // to 72];
```

After shuffle ***ar*** :

```
shuffle(ar);
```

Then to show random image create variable for each 22 images

```
var img0 = "img_" + ar[0] + ".png";
var img1 = "img_" + ar[1] + ".png";
```

And **img0** and **img1** are random images from your list

Comment: // There are and shorter ways but this is the way that I used as a beginner

Comment: The shuffle function changes the first value of the array with another random number from the array without repeat.

Comment: after you shuffle all elements in array "ar"

Comment: and then when you call the image you call each image with a random number "img_" + ar[0] + ".png";. The random number here is "ar[0]"

Comment: why you need the images? the images are called like img_1 and img_2 and img_3 and so on... until img_72

Comment: I thought that you have added images with link. OK